# Facebook Bangla font Problem in google chrome

Tags: fonts, google-chrome

I am using google chrome (not chromium) in ubuntu 11.10. I have installed all bangla fonts, set encode to unicode and set bangla font in chrome. It shows all bangla fonts excepts facebook profile name. Chrome show blank box instead of facebook bangla profile name. But it shows the bangla profile name in title bar. What kind of problem is this? How can i solve this?

image example: [see, title bar shows the bangla profile name]

[image]

Note: I am using latest google chrome. It shows something link this 15.0.874.121 in chrome about window. i can't find any version.

**EDITED VERSION:**
I discover more. See the image below
[image]

In inspect element bangla [একাদশে বৃহস্পতি] is showing but in browser is block. Other bangla is working in chrome like that,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    </head>
    <body>
        কি খবর দাদা?
    </body>
</html>
```

Above code shows perfectly in chrome.

Comment: This is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=48298&q=bangla&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary . For now, may be you could use Firefox.

Comment: Do you still have the issue? What is the purpose of the bounty you just started?

Comment: I have solved the problem after the bounty started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with newer chrome. It fixed in version 17.0.963.79. So the problem was previous version bug.

Comment: This problem is still present in Chrome version 28, 29 in 13.04. Might not be a version bug.

Answer (score 8):

The problem might not be version bug as other answer suggesting, since it is still in chrome 29. A more concrete solution could be this.

1. First Download a standard Bangla font, such as [Solaiman Lipi](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/ekushey/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf).
2. Install the font by copying it to either your user specific `~/.fonts` folder or for system-wide effect in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` folder.
3. Then close (if it is opened) and open the Google chrome.
4. Go to *Settings*, click on *Advanced settings*, in *Website content* section, click on the *customize fonts* button.
5. In the *sans-serif* font section, change the font to *Solaiman Lipi*.

This should solve the problem.

Credit: [This page on blogspot](http://bangla-font-problem.blogspot.com/)

**Some alternative fonts:**

You could also install lohit bengali font and use it. to install use the command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-lohit-beng-bengali
```

Or you might want to test some of the fonts from [omicron-lab site](http://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html)

Comment: Fonts can be installed with the default font viewer as well.